# Document Link Target New Window

Tags: wygwam

Can the target tab drop down be defaulted to "open in new window" when linking to uploaded docs?

Answer (score 1):

You could easily do this with jquery on the front end of the site.

```
//all pdf links with a will open in a new window
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("a[href$=".pdf"]").attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Change the selector as needed if you only want to target pdfs on a certain page/div/ etc...